# Naming convention for class that interact with database

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

Is there such thing as standard naming convention for a class that interact with database ( CRUD things or check duplication ). Right now i just named it as Helper, for example a named "Subscriptions" A class that 
interact with that table will be named "SubscriptionHelper"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LoopinWineBackOffice.Helper
{
    public class SubscriberHelper
    {
        public static bool IsEmailAlreadyInUsed(string email)
        {
            using (var dc = new LoopinWiineContainer())
            {
               return dc.Subscribers.Any(item => item.Email==email.Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My sample code is something like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my experience [and no offense intended] when classes start getting names like 'Helper' and 'Manager' it's because the purpose of that class hasn't been well defined (and I have been guilty of this in the past myself).

In this case, I would speculate that you haven't really thought about your data access pattern, and you've just got a bunch of ad-hoc SQL in the 'SubscriptionHelper' class.

Now, if you were implementing a standard data access pattern, for example a Repository pattern, your class would be called SubscriptionRepository, and its intent would be alot clearer.

So, in answer to the question - No, I don't think there is a standard 'naming' convention for your scenario. What there are though, are several standard design patterns which you could potentially apply to your system, and through doing so, you would likely end up with a naming convention which is both informative, and meaningful.

Here's a starting point for some well known design patterns for you: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/, but without knowing more about the project, it would be hard to direct you much further than that.

Comment: I concure - you should be thinking patterns not naming conventions. e.g. MVC or Repository. There are plenty of data frameworks in .Net also - EF - LINQ - ADO ...

Comment: I don't think there's any shame in ending up with a bunch of functions that just interact with data. I often do, and when their common purpose becomes clear I refactor into something more meaningful.

Comment: I agree, it's easy to get bogged down trying to lay out code in a certain way right from the start. Letting the code become the architecture it needs to be, through constant testing and refactoring. Should produce well defined groupings of code that are easy to read and exist to do one thing well. Ultimately meaning the naming becomes the easy part over time. The key thing though with this approach is testing and refactoring, which must be part of day to day coding or this approach falls flat on its back.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there such thing as standard naming convention for a class that interact with database

Yes, how about following the Table Data Gateway pattern, in which case you'd have a "Subscriber Gateway" object for accessing a single table or view: selects, inserts, updates, and deletes.

Table Data Gateway: An object that acts as a Gateway to a database table. 
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html